# Internet Explorer jQuery getJSON not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

im making a small script which gets some data from a database through php using jquery's getJSON method.

the code as shown below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var id = userid;
$('#a-div').after('<div id="data"></div><input type="button" id="getdata" value="Get Data">');

       $('#getdata').click(function(){
        $.getJSON('http://mysite.com/data.php?id=' + id, function(data) {
           var notfound = data['notfound'];
           var user = data['user'];
           if(notfound == '1'){      
             $('#data').html("Not found");
           } 
           else{   
            $('#data').html("Found , user is "+ user);
           }
         });//end of getJSON
       });//end of click
 }); //end of document ready
```

My php script returns JSON data something like this :
If the data is found in database-

```
{"notfound":"0","user":"john"}
```

If the data is NOT found in database-

```
{"notfound":"1","user":"none"}
```

This works perfectly on Firefox , Google Chrome and Safari , just dosent work in Internet Explorers(7,8,9)
can anyone help me out.

P/S i have tried a few techniques in other posts similar to this one , is not working.
Like changing the the META content-type

Thanks.

Comment: are there js errors on the page??

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Is the response callback not being called at all, or is `data` not being set to the object you expect, or can you not access the object's properties as you expect, or...?

Comment: I found the answer it's the callback=? i forgotten to include it into the getJSON url.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the button *inside* of the <body> like so:

```
 $("body").append( /* markup for div and btn here */ );
```

...instead of using after().

Comment: .after is working in IE , i tried .append , its not working yet.

Comment: JSON getting the data and display it out

Comment: So, what does it display? In other words, does execution ever get to your if / else?

Comment: Wait a second - looking at your other comments, are you getting something about "cannot send cross-domain message"? Is the target URL of your getJSON() call from a domain *other than* the one from which you're making the request...?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe internet explorer  is taking long time to add the html, try with live

```
$('#getdata').live('click', function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using very ugly code, after body incorrect to write any HTML content, for that you must add in body any div and append your cod to it, and then this code will work in IEs

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#anydiv').html('<div id="data"></div><input type="button" id="getdata" value="Get Data">');

    $('#getdata').click(function () {
        alert("asd");
        $.getJSON('/HowItWork/Index?id=' + 23, function (data) {
            var notfound = data['notfound'];
            var user = data['user'];
            if (notfound == '1') {
                $('#data').html("Not found");
            }
            else {
                $('#data').html("Found , user is " + user);
            }
        }); //end of getJSON
    }); //end of click
}); //end of document ready
```

Comment: sorry still not working , the internet explorer giving me an error "No Relay Set(used as window.postMessage targetOrigin),cannot send cross-domain message"

Comment: I have writen this in ASP.NET MVC application and this is work even in IE 7, maybe you have any other issue, for example in server side

Comment: I've seen where folks get told to keep their cod to themselves, but this has got to be the first I've ever seen someone ordered to append their cod to anything!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me- `jQuery.support.cors = true;`

Find more discussion http://jquery.10927.n7.nabble.com/jQuery-getJSON-response-not-working-with-IE-works-perfectly-in-firefox-safari-td81254.html